# How do I find (index) file in order to change style on CSS?

Tags: css, theme-twenty-sixteen

I am using the basic twenty sixteen theme and I am trying to edit some of the features. For instance I want to edit the sidebar on the right.

[image]

However, when I open the inspector, it says that the border color is on (index):198.

[image]

Where do I find that?

Comment: This is the website: https://blog.drosiatea.gr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS code you refer to is dynamically generated by the theme. The color is set in the customizer under 'Colors' -> 'Primary text color' (Or something similar). The only thin is, this setting changes the color for quite many thigs on the whole site, which is probably not what you want.

If you only want to change the color of the borders in the sidebar, you can add some more specific CSS via a plugin or a in a child theme:

```
#secondary .widget {
    border-color: #123456;
}
```

This will then override the generated CSS as it uses a more specific selector.

Comment: @Andrilio could you please mark the answer as accepted then? That is a nice way to say thank you and also marks the question as having an accepted answer.